# How can I convert a Joda's Duration to a java.time.Duration?

Tags: java, jodatime, java-time

I want to parse a string like `1d2h3m4s` into a `java.time.Duration`. I can use a joda's `PeriodFormatter` to parse the string into a `org.joda.time.Duration` but I can't figure out how to convert that to a standard Java8's `java.time.Duration`.

I have to interface to some "legacy" code that already expects `java.time.Duration` as input, but I want to use joda's `parsePeriod` because the `java.time.Duration.parse()` only accepts ISO-8601 duration format (`1d2h3m4s` is not ISO-8601 duration compliant)

```
import org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormatter;
import org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormatterBuilder;

...

final PeriodFormatter periodFormatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
        .printZeroNever()
        .appendDays().appendSuffix("d")
        .appendHours().appendSuffix("h")
        .appendMinutes().appendSuffix("m")
        .appendSeconds().appendSuffix("s").toFormatter();

org.joda.time.Duration myduration = periodFormatter.parsePeriod("1d1s").toStandardDuration(); 
java.util.time myduration2 = XXXXX
```

Please bear in mind that I'm not trying to remove the usage of `org.joda.time.Period` from my code like in [Converting org.joda.time.Period to java.time.Period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47217098/converting-org-joda-time-period-to-java-time-period). I still want to have a `org.joda.time.Period` because I have more parsing option to generate those, and I need a `java.time.Period`/`java.time.Duration` because I interact with some other API/libraries that expect `java.time.*`.

So, is there a way to convert a `org.joda.time.Duration` to a `java.time.Duration`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting org.joda.time.Period to java.time.Period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47217098/converting-org-joda-time-period-to-java-time-period)

Comment: Not really, in that question the OP is not trying to convert one instance of `org.joda.time.Period` to an instance of `java.time.Period` at all. He is asking how to *replace* a joda's `Period` with a `java.time.Period` , so he won't have any joda's instance at all. I want to have both a joda's `Period` (because I  have more options to parse there)  and a `java.time.Period` (well `java.time.Duration` ) because I have other code that expects the input in this type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am presenting three options

1. Hand modify the string to ISO 8601 format so that `java.time.Duration` can parse it.
2. Convert through count of milliseconds.
3. Convert from `joda.time.Duration.toString()`.

### Modify the string

Personally I don’t think I would want to depend in Joda-Time for this. Instead I would modify your non-ISO 8601 string to ISO 8601 format.

```
    String durationString = "1d1s";
    // Convert to ISO 8601 format
    String isoString = durationString.replaceFirst("(.*?[Dd])?(.*)", "P$1T$2");
    java.time.Duration dur = java.time.Duration.parse(isoString);
    System.out.println(dur);
```

Output is:

> PT24H1S

I admit that the regular expression is a bit hard to read. If there is an uppercase or lowercase `D` in the string, everything up to and including that `D` is placed before the `T` in the ISO string. Everything else is placed after the `T`.

### Convert over milliseconds

This is an idea similar to the one in the answer by ecerulm. I didn’t want to lose the millisecond precision of the Joda-Time duration, so I rely of milliseconds rather than seconds (I know that for your example strings it will make no difference).

```
    final PeriodFormatter periodFormatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
            .printZeroNever()
            .appendDays().appendSuffix("d")
            .appendHours().appendSuffix("h")
            .appendMinutes().appendSuffix("m")
            .appendSeconds().appendSuffix("s").toFormatter();

    org.joda.time.Duration myduration = periodFormatter.parsePeriod("1d1s").toStandardDuration(); 

    java.time.Duration dur = java.time.Duration.ofMillis(myduration.getMillis());
```

The result is the same as before.

### Convert over a string

```
    java.time.Duration dur = java.time.Duration.parse(myduration.toString());
```

Again the result is the same. Formatting the duration into an ISO 8601 string only to parse it back feels like a waste, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can just convert the `org.joda.time.Period` returned by `PeriodFormatter#parse()` to seconds using `Period#toStandardSeconds()#getSeconds()`. That will give you the number of seconds as an `int`

Then use `java.time.Duration.ofSeconds()` to create a `java.time.Duration` from that `int`.

```
import org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormatterBuilder
import org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormatter

PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
        .printZeroNever()
        .appendDays().appendSuffix("d")
        .appendHours().appendSuffix("h")
        .appendMinutes().appendSuffix("m")
        .appendSeconds().appendSuffix("s")
        .toFormatter();

Period myPeriod = formatter.parsePeriod("1d2h3m4s");

java.time.Duration myDuration = java.time.Duration.ofSeconds(
        myPeriod.toStandardSeconds().getSeconds());
```